# Емкость (capacity) и заполненность (load factor) для HashMap

Tags: коллекции, hashcode

Господа,
поймал себя на том, что не понимаю базовых вещей по `Hash-коллекциям`.

Предположим, переопределили `hashCode()` таким образом, что он равен для всех экземпляров класса, который используется в качестве ключа `HashMap` (или значения `HashSet`).
Значит ли это, что фактически все заносимые в коллекцию `Entry` окажутся в одной-единственной "корзине",
или все же будет создано некоторое количество корзин (по умолчанию, кажется, 16), в каждой из которых элементы ключи имеют один и тот же код?

Известно также, что при достижении `load factor (0.75)` происходит динамическое перераспеределение корзин. Но тогда вновь вопрос - а в чем же здесь роль специфической реализации `hashCode()`, если все подстраивается по каким-то внутренним алгоритмам hash-коллекций?

Answer (score 4):

Я бы очень рекомендовал книгу Effective Java, автор Joshua Bloch (есть и на русском языке). Там описано очень много нюансов работы с Java, которые могут сильно повлиять на ваш код.

По первому вопросу:
Вы правы, вот выдержка из выше приведенной книги (Item 9: Always override hashCode when you override equals)

> ```
> // The worst possible legal hash function - never use!
> @Override public int hashCode() { return 42; }
> ```
>
> It’s legal because it ensures that equal objects have the same hash
>   code. It’s atrocious because it ensures that *every* object has the
>   same hash code. Therefore, every object hashes to the same bucket, and
>   hash tables degenerate to linked lists.

Таким образов, все элементы оказываются в одной корзине и все элементы будут сравниваться через `equals`.

Про второй вопрос не очень понятно, но постараюсь ответить. Грубо говоря для определения места в `HashMap` мы будем использовать операцию деления по модулю (т.е. `hashCode() & n`, где `n` - количество корзин являющееся степенью двойки). Таким образом при увеличении количества корзин произойдет перераспределение (пересчет места в таблице) для нового размера. Но если, как в первом вопросе, функция `hashCode()` будет возвращать одинаковые значения, но никакое перераспределение не поможет, элементы останутся в одной корзине. В том и смысл - если хэш функция генерирует более равномерные результаты, корзины будут заполняться равномерно, не будет большого количества пустых корзин и перераспределение будет более эффективным.

Советую так же прочитать:

1. [Структуры данных в картинках. HashMap](http://habrahabr.ru/post/128017/)
2. [Джошуа Блох, Java. Эффективное программирование](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/21724143/)
3. [Joshua Bloch, Effective Java](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321356683)

Comment: Боюсь, вы не поняли, что меня мучает :) По крайней мере, ответа на свой вопрос я не обнаружил.
Приведу конкретный пример.
Пусть hashCode как в вашем примере (примере Joshua Bloch)
@Override public int hashCode() { return 42; }
При этом конструируя HashMap я explicitly указываю количество объектов в корзине (связном списке), напр., 16. 
Добавляю в карту 24 элемента (учитывая load factor 0.75 это количество элементов наполнило бы 2 корзины)
Окажутся ли они все в одной или все же в разных корзинах?
А если не указывать initial capacity в конструкторе - что-то изменится?

Comment: @AndreyM.Stepanov вы указываете `capacity`, которая определяет размер таблицы (количество корзин) как `(capacity * loadFactor)`, а не количество элементов в корзине. Теоретически количество элементов в корзине не ограничено, т.к. это просто связный список и он будет содержать все элементы, как я и написал в ответе. Однако количество корзин будет расти, но использоваться они не будут.